# Why echo is necessary in php inside html files, in this example?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I wonder:

why I this code is valid:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">go to this post</a>
```

but for retrieving the following value I must use **echo**, or else it won't work:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>">back to homepage</a>
```

I took a glance at [get_option documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) and it said that:

> Return# - (mixed) Value set for the option.

So perhaps that is the different, that the return value of this function is not a string?

Comment: Because Wordpress decided to use some functions which `return` the value, and some others which `echo` the value. Just read the doc for each function.

Comment: `the_*` functions typically output right away, whereas `get_*` funcs return values in WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_permalink()` calls echo within the function call. See the [full source here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/). `get_option()` only returns a value so you have to echo it explicitly if you want it in the html.

Comment: Thanks, a very basic question, apperently. It has been a while since I last coded php...

Answer (score 0):

I' m not sure, but if you review the `the_permalink();` method's body you may see `echo` command at the end of the method while `get_option('home');` just return a string as  the result.